# JsonPath with Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: json, json.net, jsonpath

I tried for nearly an hour different approaches, but I don't get it ;(

my JSON object is this:

```
"typeOfHair": {
    "value": [
        {
            "code": "Dry Hair",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "DryHair",
                    "language": "en"
                },
                {
                    "value": "TrockenesHaar",
                    "language": "de"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "Any Type of Hair",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "AnyTypeOfHair",
                    "language": "en"
                },
                {
                    "value": "JedenHaartyp",
                    "language": "de"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And my task is to get with Newtonsoft.JSON all values where the language is "de".
My current approach is:

```
JsonObject.SelectTokens("typeOfHair.value.values[?(@.language == 'de')].value").ToList()
```

Can someone help me with this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close.  You need to account for the outer `value` array `typeOfHair.value[]` by using the [JsonPATH](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard operator `[*]`:

```
var values = JsonObject.SelectTokens("typeOfHair.value[*].values[?(@.language == 'de')].value")
    // Convert from JValue to string
    .Select(v => (string)v)
    // Save in a list
    .ToList();
```

And, the result is:

```
["TrockenesHaar","JedenHaartyp"]
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MrxqtO).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

I know the OP specified JSONPath explicitly but for the sake of completeness below is how to achieve the same with LINQ to JSON:

```
var values = jObject["typeOfHair"]["value"]
    .SelectMany(v => v["values"])
    .Where(v => (string)v["language"] == "de")
    .Select(v => (string)v["value"])
    .ToList();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1S4sT4